# How to prevent Flash components from blocking Firefox's keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: firefox, flash

Whenever a flash code takes control in Firefox, Firefox's keyboard shortcuts stop functioning. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [**Flash Player FAQ**](http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/faqs/flash.html#keyboard-shortcuts)

> **Keyboard shortcuts can not be used when Flash Player is loaded**
>
> This is a known problem with all plugins, not just Flash Player.
> There are several bugs filed on this issue. [[Bug List](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_id=78414%2C93149%2C140566%2C181177)]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are having this problem when you are specifically trying to look at flash, you should definitely install the [Flash Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433) extension.  It's one of the best as it means you only have to look at the flash you want to see, when you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this recently, and if you're running Linux, you can follow the [somewhat complicated instructions to create your own extension](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-78414-firefox-flash/index.html?ca=drs-), which monitors the system keyboard input.